# Error: Could not find or load main class Boolean

Tags: java, class, boolean

I am new to Java and specially new to StackOver Flow, so sorry if I sound like a noob, this is my very first post on here

Anyway I am learning how to do Boolean Arguments and whenever I try to Compile my program it comes up with an error

Here is my Code, I use Edit Plus

```
class Boolean_1
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
    static boolean i = true;
    static boolean j = false;

    System.out.print.ln ("Condition \t Result");
    System.out.print.ln ("true and true \t" + (i&&i));
    System.out.print.ln ("true and false \t" + (i&&j));
    System.out.print.ln ("false and true \t" + (j&&i));
    System.out.print.ln ("false and false" + (j&&j));


    }
}
```

Can someone help me out, and even help me with the Boolean stuff if they can :D

Kind Regards 
Utkarsh Anand

Comment: You're adding `static` to local variables and using `out.print.ln` instead of `out.println`.

Comment: You're trying to declare static variables within a method. Either remove the "static" from the variable declarations to make them local variables, or move the declarations outside the method. I wouldn't expect that to cause the error in your title though - if you have further problems, please show *exactly* how you're compiling and trying to run the code, as well as include the exact error message in the body of your question.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, I fixed all that, but I am getting the same Error

Comment: When asking this sort of question, please copy-and-paste the _exact_ error message in. It makes it much easier for us to help.

Answer (score 1):

Few errors to be pointed out is :-

1. It is `System.out.println()` and not `System.out.print.ln()`.
2. You can't declare variables as `static` within a method. It should be within a class outside of any method.

So,correct code for it is :-

```
class Boolean_1
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        boolean i = true;
        boolean j = false;

        System.out.println ("Condition \t Result");
        System.out.println ("true and true \t" + (i && i));
        System.out.println ("true and false \t" + (i && j));
        System.out.println ("false and true \t" + (j && i));
        System.out.println ("false and false" + (j && j));
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, I fixed all that, but I am getting the same Error

Comment: @user3742134 can you explain the error that you are getting?

Comment: @user3605029 as specified by "The same Error", he's referring to the one in the topic: `Error: Could not find or load main class Boolean`.

Comment: @Unihedron-As visible from his error,how come his class name be `Boolean`---Java won't allow this even at the time of creation of the Class? I think he has problem with declaration of his project name in the EditPlus IDE!

Comment: Yeah, but that's why I named it Boolean_1, not just Boolean

Comment: @user3742134 please post exact error message or complete code

Comment: @user3742134 compile using filename Eg. `javac filename.java` and run only using class name  `java Boolean_1` here if class is not public

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the answers written below, you also need a `public` class. Change class declaration to `public class Boolean_1`.

This is so the class loader is able to gain entry.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `static` from both boolean and the method you have to call for an output is called `println` (without dot)